# Есть ли утилиты для автоматизации процесса поиска и установка драйверов?

Tags: windows-7, драйвер

Перешёл с windows 10 на windows 7. Нужно установить драйвера. Есть ли утилиты для автоматизации процесса поиска и установка драйверов.

Comment: С этими утилитами надо быть аккуратнее, они много лишнего ставят в систему. А вообще есть DriverPack Solution. Но лучше не полениться и на сайте производителя искать дрова под каждую железку отдельно

Comment: Я установил несколько драйверов с официального сайта. Но есть устройства на которые драйвера не нашёл.

Comment: *есть устройства на которые драйвера не нашёл* В диспетчере оборудования смотришь VEN/DEV (`VEN_xxxx&DEV__yyyy`), по этой подстроке определяешь устройство, и по ней же ищешь драйверы для него (должно быть явно прописано в соотв. .INF-файле).

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.